# How can one find the root of sesquilinear form with positive definite matrix?

Tags: matrices

I cane accross the problem of this kind dealing with fuzzy regression analysis.
$$(x^{T}Mx)^{1/2}$$
I would like to know how this root can be expressed explictly using x. (Here of course x is $(n \times 1)$ real-valued column, and M is $(n \times n)$ positive-definite matrix, so the above form is some inner product. And of course it has only one root, as it is a real number.) 
I wonder whether there are some formulas for that or not?

Thank you.

I mean finding the root, in some form. That is having expression where x is out of the parenthesis.

Comment: It is a norm, not an inner product. It is already explicitly depending on $x$. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by root that $(x^T M x)^(1/2)  =  0$, then $x^T M x = 0$, then $x$ should fall in the null space of $M$. Therefore, $x$ is a vector the lies in the null-space of $M$.

Comment: I think it is root as in  square root and not zero of a function.